Intuition for proximal point method using L2 regularization
To minimize a function $f$, the proximal point method is defined as
$$x_{k+1} := \operatorname*{argmin}_x f(x) + \frac{1}{2\eta}\|x - x_k\|^2.$$
What's the intuition for why we want to use L2 regularization and not some higher order for example, since it seems like all we require is convexity?

One reason for adding quadratic regularisation is that it (can) make[s] the inner problem 'more' convex (in the sense of strong / uniform convexity), which makes it appreciably easier to solve in many cases.

I think one should prefer a penalty term that is strongly convex (so as not to be too forgiving) and and also analytically as simple as possible. For either one of these reasons, you cannot beat the isotropic quadratic penalty.
